# How can I fix an error with IBus in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ubuntu-15.04, intellij-15

> Installed: 
>   Ubuntu 15.10 x64 
>   Kernel: 4.2.0-18-generic 
>   IBus 1.5.11 
>   java version "1.8.0_66" 
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17) 
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode) 
>   IntelliJ IDEA 15

Hello guys. I've got a problem with IntelliJ IDEA 15 in Ubuntu 15.10. when I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, sometimes I can't use hotkeys (for example: ctrl+v, ctrl+a and etc.) in IntelliJ. I've seen a notification about IBus in IDE, I'd followed by instructions to fix that, but it didn't solve a problem, I've added "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" to my ~/.profile, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using vim plugin?

Comment: Did you restart your X session after you changed the value? Did you make sure the variable is set after you logged in again?

Comment: No I'm not. Yes I did, but I'm not sure about variable.